# CS0234: The type or name space name 'VSConstants' doesn't exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Currently my application is on .net framework 4.8 in visual studio 2019 . I need  to shift the source code to visual studio 2022 in pipeline but the **VSConstants** class I am unable to load it in visual studio 2022.In vs 2019 it works fine. I have tried to update the Visual studio package ,but didn't work.

```
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.VSStd97CmdID
```

VSConstants shows that it doesnot exist in namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio ,Is there any way to fix this in vs2022.

Comment: Did you install the C++/CX SDKs when installing VS2022?

Comment: I have installed C++/CLI support for v1.43 build tools (latest),C++ ATL for latest v143 build tools (x86 & x64),C++ MFC for latest v143 build tools (x86 & x64) these packages .